# replaceAll does not replace string

Tags: java, android, regex, string, stringbuffer

I want the text "REPLACEME" to be replaced with my StringBuffer symbols. When I print symbols, it is a valid string. When I print my query, it still has the text REPLACEME instead of symbols. Why?

```
private String buildQuery(){
    String query = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(REPLACEME)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";

    deserializeQuotes();

    StringBuffer symbols = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < quotes.size();i++){
        if(i == (quotes.size()-1))
            symbols.append("%22" + quotes.get(i).getSymbol() + "%22%"); //end with a quote
        else
            symbols.append("%22" + quotes.get(i).getSymbol() + "%22%2C");
    }

    System.out.println("***SYMBOLS***" + symbols.toString());
    query.replaceAll("REPLACEME", symbols.toString());

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change

```
query.replaceAll("REPLACEME", symbols.toString());
```

to:

```
query = query.replaceAll("REPLACEME", symbols.toString());
```

Strings in Java are designed to be [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).
That is why `replaceAll()` can't replace the characters **in** the current string, so it must return a **new** string with the characters replaced.

---

Also if you want to simply replace literals and don't need regex syntax support use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` (regex syntax support is only difference between these two methods). It is safer in case you would want to replace literals which can contain regex metacharacters like `*`, `+`, `[`, `]` [and others](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special).

Comment: Also note, strings are immutable in Java. You can NEVER change a string in place.

Comment: I always forget this xD

Answer (score 6):

Read the documentation :) replaceAll() returns a new String, it does replace inside the existing String. The reason for that is that Strings are immutable objects.

Answer (score 5):

The String object in Java is immutable. The replaceAll will not replace the data in the string, it will generate a new string. Try this:

```
query = query.replaceAll("REPLACEME", symbols.toString());
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the immutability of String.