# Can't replace string with regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace a string occurrence in a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE AGE = 3 and NAME = 'VALUE'
```

I'm using this regex: `NAME\s*=\s*'[A-Z]+'` that works fine [here](http://regexr.com/)

This is how I've tried in Java:

```
query.replaceAll("NAME\s*=\s*'[A-Z]+'", replacementString); // Gives me Invalid escape sequence message
query.replaceAll("NAME\\s*=\\s*'[A-Z]+'", replacementString); 

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("NAME*= *'[A-Z]*'");
query.replaceAll(pattern.pattern(), replacementString);

Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("NAME\\s*=\\s*'[A-Z]*'");                
query.replaceAll(pattern2.pattern(), replacementString);
```

None of this work.

How can I replace the NAME = 'VALUE' occurrence?

Comment: Escape your backslashes: `\\s*` to fix the "invalid escape sequence" error.

Comment: Precausion: make sure "VALUE" never contains `'`, otherwise simple regex won't suffice.

Comment: The problem is with the `query.replaceAll(pattern2.pattern(), replacementString);` - you need to assign the value to a string variable.

Comment: VALUE never contains `'`

Comment: `"NAME\\s*=\\s*'[A-Z]*'"` is ok to use. You can also use `"NAME\\s*=\\s*'[^']*'"`. If you need to use a compiled pattern, use it with the Matcher, see [demo](http://ideone.com/frn3iQ). But that is just an enhancement. Your main problem is with the modified value assignment.

Comment: **No, it works after you assign the value: see [this demo](https://ideone.com/ArkWDm)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java strings are immutable.

You need to assign the result of the `replaceAll` call back to the string:

```
query = query.replaceAll(...);
```

Comment: Why post an evident answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611635/java-regex-replaceall-does-not-replace-string

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
query.replaceAll("NAME\\s*=\\s*'[A-Z]+'", replacementString); 
query.replaceAll("NAME\\s*=\\s*'[A-Z]+'", replacementString);
```

And then in your pattern,

```
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("NAME\\s*=\\s*'[A-Z]*'");                
query.replaceAll(pattern2.pattern(), replacementString);
```

Comment: What if OP wants to first compile the pattern?

Comment: Already tried, it doesn't work